# Building Assimp solution with Visual Studio 2017 yields 'This app can't run on your PC'

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, assimp

I'm attempting to install Assimp for my OpenGL project.

After creating the solution with CMake and attempting to build the solution, I'm met with a Windows error reading "This app can't run on your PC".

I'm running on 64 bit and I attempted both the Win32 and x64 configuration in CMake with no luck.

I've also first tried to make a build for Visual Studio 2019 but that didn't work so I downgraded to 2017 because of online recommendations.

I prefer to try and build the 32 bit version though because my OpenGL project is.

Here is the complete error code I received when trying to build.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ZERO_CHECK, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Checking Build System
1>Access is denied.
1>D:\Program 86\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(209,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 5.
1>Done building project "ZERO_CHECK.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
2>------ Build started: Project: zlibstatic, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
3>------ Build started: Project: gtest, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
2>Building Custom Rule C:/Users/USER/Desktop/assimp-3.3.1/contrib/zlib/CMakeLists.txt
3>Creating directories for 'gtest'
3>Access is denied.
3>D:\Program 86\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(209,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 5.
3>Done building project "gtest.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
2>Access is denied.
2>D:\Program 86\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(209,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 5.
2>Done building project "zlibstatic.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
4>------ Build started: Project: assimp, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
4>Building Custom Rule C:/Users/USER/Desktop/assimp-3.3.1/code/CMakeLists.txt
4>Access is denied.
4>D:\Program 86\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(209,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 5.
4>Done building project "assimp.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
5>------ Build started: Project: assimp_cmd, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
6>------ Build started: Project: assimp_viewer, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
7>------ Build started: Project: unit, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
6>Access is denied.
6>D:\Program 86\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(128,5): error MSB3075: The command "setlocal
6>D:\Program 86\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(128,5): error MSB3075: C:\Users\USER\Desktop\cmake-3.22.2-windows-x86_64\bin\cmake.exe -E copy_if_different C:/Users/USER/Desktop/assimp-3.3.1/build/code/Debug/assimp-vc140-mt.dll C:/Users/USER/Desktop/assimp-3.3.1/build/tools/assimp_view/Debug
6>D:\Program 86\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(128,5): error MSB3075: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
6>D:\Program 86\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(128,5): error MSB3075: :cmEnd
6>D:\Program 86\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(128,5): error MSB3075: endlocal & call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto :cmDone
6>D:\Program 86\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(128,5): error MSB3075: :cmErrorLevel
6>D:\Program 86\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(128,5): error MSB3075: exit /b %1
6>D:\Program 86\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(128,5): error MSB3075: :cmDone
6>D:\Program 86\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(128,5): error MSB3075: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd
6>D:\Program 86\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(128,5): error MSB3075: :VCEnd" exited with code 5. Please verify that you have sufficient rights to run this command.
6>Done building project "assimp_viewer.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
7>Building Custom Rule C:/Users/USER/Desktop/assimp-3.3.1/test/CMakeLists.txt
7>Access is denied.
7>D:\Program 86\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(209,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 5.
7>Done building project "unit.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
5>Access is denied.
5>D:\Program 86\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(128,5): error MSB3075: The command "setlocal
5>D:\Program 86\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(128,5): error MSB3075: C:\Users\USER\Desktop\cmake-3.22.2-windows-x86_64\bin\cmake.exe -E copy_if_different C:/Users/USER/Desktop/assimp-3.3.1/build/code/Debug/assimp-vc140-mt.dll C:/Users/USER/Desktop/assimp-3.3.1/build/tools/assimp_cmd/Debug
5>D:\Program 86\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(128,5): error MSB3075: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
5>D:\Program 86\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(128,5): error MSB3075: :cmEnd
5>D:\Program 86\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(128,5): error MSB3075: endlocal & call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto :cmDone
5>D:\Program 86\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(128,5): error MSB3075: :cmErrorLevel
5>D:\Program 86\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(128,5): error MSB3075: exit /b %1
5>D:\Program 86\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(128,5): error MSB3075: :cmDone
5>D:\Program 86\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(128,5): error MSB3075: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd
5>D:\Program 86\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(128,5): error MSB3075: :VCEnd" exited with code 5. Please verify that you have sufficient rights to run this command.
5>Done building project "assimp_cmd.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
8>------ Build started: Project: ALL_BUILD, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
8>Building Custom Rule C:/Users/USER/Desktop/assimp-3.3.1/CMakeLists.txt
8>Access is denied.
8>D:\Program 86\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(209,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 5.
8>Done building project "ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
```

picture of Error
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqevH.png

Comment: The most serious error is obviously `Access is denied.`. *Where* exactly is the build supposed to happen? And are you really user `USER` on your system, or is that supposed to be an environment variable?

Comment: @BoP I created the solution in CMake to the directory C:/Users/USER/Desktop/assimp-3.3.1/build and I build it there. By the way, I'm user USER on my computer, and to add I tried rebuilding and cleaning the solution but still got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you copied the source directory into your Desktop-directory. Please make sure that the directory is not read-only:

1. Open an explorer-window
2. Right-click the assimp-folder
3. Deselect read-only if this is selected.

Kim